# Common header and footer in HTML, should I use JavaScript, PHP or other for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, php, javascript

Firstly, I am aware this question is similar to others asked in the paste, however I'm specifically asking about the reliability of SEO in this question (also many of the other questions are outdated).

I have developed a new website in HTML, where the header and footer are the same on every page (obviously).

I'm currently using jQuery to inject them into every page using:

```
 $("#loadHeader").load("header.html");
 $("#loadFooter").load("footer.html");
```

This works, however as it's client side I'm assuming search engines won't see any of the content stored in header.html, therefore SEO will not work for any of the headers/footers, on any of the pages?

If I use PHP to inject the headers/footers, will SEO work as if they were included directly in the HTML?

If not, are there any other ways around this issue?

Comment: This was asked just a few days ago. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102592/seo-for-importing-the-page-header-with-javascript-rather-than-php There is a difference. Some SEs will render JS, however, do not rely upon it. Server side will send complete HTML which is preferred in my opinion. PHP results in fewer requests to the server, decreases load time, does not rely on the user allowing JS, better control, on and on.

Comment: @closetnoc but why at all should we allow search engines to index header and footer added by JavaScript? Such parts don't have valuable content. We can just check if a user agent is a bot or a human and load common part only for the human